# Is it possible in java to recognise file types other then just file or directory?

Tags: java, file-io

On Unix system we have 7 different file types 
Below snippet from "man ls"

```
    Regular file        -
    Directory           d
    Character Device    c
    Block Device        b
    Local Domain Socket s
    Named Pipe          p
    Symbolic Link       l
```

In java.io.File we have only methods like isFile, isDirectory, isHidden
Is it possible in java to recognise file types other then just file or directory ?

Answer (score 0):

[java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) (from Java 7) methods supports extended attributes for files. This gives more flexibility to get [POSIX attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributes.html). I don't see support for distinguishing those file types, however.

Answer (score 0):

With Java7 you can at least check for [symbolic links](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isSymbolicLink%28%29). You can also check to see if the path is a [regular file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isRegularFile%28%29) but I don't know how that would behave if ran against a block device or named pipe.